# Unable to open ejabbered web dashboard localhost:5280

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, smack, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-auth

I am new to ejabberd and trying to play with it. I installed ejabbered following the instructions present at official doc page with username and password. I am able to start the ejabbered server and connect to it through Java using "Smack" API's.

However, when I try to open Web Dashboard at http://localhost:5280/admin/ and then login with admin user, It doesn't show up anything. When I checked logs, it shows following erros -

`2020-03-13 21:03:17.618 [error] <0.1965.0>@ejabberd_http:apply_custom_headers:860 CRASH REPORT Process <0.1965.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: bad argument in call to maps:from_list([html]) in ejabberd_http:apply_custom_headers/2 line 860`

`2020-03-13 21:03:17.619 [error] <0.535.0>@ejabberd_http:apply_custom_headers:860 Supervisor ejabberd_http_sup had child undefined started with {ejabberd_http,start_link,undefined} at <0.1965.0> exit with reason bad argument in call to maps:from_list([html]) in ejabberd_http:apply_custom_headers/2 line 860 in context child_terminated`

Pleasse help me out with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that problem was introduced in ejabberd 20.02, and it's fixed in the following versions.

You have two options:

- Download ejabberd 20.01, that doesn't have this problem
- Or download ejabberd 20.03 or above.